# Why is the set $E=\{x\in X \:| \exists N \in \mathbb N \forall n>N d(T^n x,x) \geq \epsilon\} $ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to prove a theorem in Ergodic Theory, in which I want to be able to use a set being measureable, but I don't find it too easy to understand why it is. Wounder if you could help.

Let $T:\:X\to X$ be a continuous function on a $(X,d)$ compact metric space, with a probability Borel measure $\mu$ on it. let $\epsilon >0$.
Define $E=\{x\in X \:| \exists N \in \mathbb N \:\forall n>N \:d(T^n x,x) \geq \epsilon\} $.

my question is why (if?) $E$ is measureable.
in that context $T^n=T\circ T\circ \cdots \circ T$ $n$ times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that: $$E=\bigcup_{N\in\mathbb N}\bigcap_{n>N}\{x\in X\mid d(T^nx,x)\geq\epsilon\}$$

Countable intersections/unions of measurable sets are measurable, so measurability of $\{x\in X\mid d(T^nx,x)\geq\epsilon\}$ is enough for measurability of $E$.

That on its turn can be seen as a consequence of measurability of the function prescribed by $x\mapsto d(T^nx,x)$.

This function can be looked at as composition $g\circ h$ where $h:X\to X\times X$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto\langle T^nx,x\rangle$ and $g:X\times X\to\mathbb R$ as $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto d(x,y)$.

If $h$ and $g$ are measurable, then so is their composition.

Can you prove yourself that $h$ and $g$ are measurable?

Comment: yes I can. thanks for you help! I can only imagine this argument is quite usefull.

Comment: You are welcome.